# SFINAE and order of definition

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

Consider this simple SFINAE test to determine if a type can be an argument to `std::begin`

```
#include <utility>

    template <class T> constexpr auto
std_begin_callable (T const*) -> decltype (std::begin (std::declval <T>()), bool ()) 
{ return true; }

    template <class> constexpr bool
std_begin_callable (...) 
{ return false; }

#include <array>

static_assert (std_begin_callable <std::array <int, 3>> (0), "failed");

int main () {}
```

Note that the `array` header, in which the specialization for `std::begin` is defined, is included *after* the SFINAE functions. The assertion fails. Now if I move the `#include <array>` before, it works. (gcc 4.8.0 20130411, clang version 3.2)

I don't understand why. The SFINAE functions being templates, shouldn't they be instanciated when needed, in the static assertion, after the inclusion of the header defining the function they test?

The problem is that my SFINAE being in a header, I must ensure that it is included *after* any other container header (this issue is not specifically linked to the `array` header).

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to add specializations to a template after the template has already been used elsewhere.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Are you sure that is relevant in this case? After all, the first use that would cause an implicit instantiation is in the `static_assert`

Comment: @AndyProwl: I'm like 90% sure or so. I believe this has been discussed before, and that's the conclusion we came to. I might be wrong, of course.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I see. I am not sure how to interpret 14.7.3/6: "*If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that specialization
shall be declared before the **first use** of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation
to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs*".

Comment: It seems to me "first use" is ambiguous

Comment: Whaaaat. First of all, `begin` and `end` are defined in `<iterator>`. Next, `<array>` doesn't have any specialization of those two, the ones that forward to member `begin`/`end` suffice completely. Also, you can't partially specialize function templates, so it'd never work for `std::array` anyways.

Comment: Well OK, sorry for the specialization thing, my mistake. Yet I still don't understand why it works in one case and not in the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **[Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo) said**, to make it work you must `#include <iterator>` to bring in the appropriate  definition of `begin`. More precisely, this works:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

template <class T> constexpr auto
std_begin_callable (T const*) -> decltype (std::begin (std::declval <T>()), bool ()) 
{ return true; }

template <class> constexpr bool
std_begin_callable (...) 
{ return false; }

#include <array>

static_assert (std_begin_callable <std::array <int, 3>> (0), "failed");

int main () {}
```

Now, let's see why the original code which doesn't include `<iterator>` compiles but doesn't give the expected result (unless you move the `#include <array>` up).

The inclusion of `<utility>` indirectly implies the inclusion of `<initializer_list>` which defines `std::begin(std::initializer_list<T>)`. Therefore, in this translation unit the name `std::begin` is visible.

However, when you call `std_begin_callable` the first overload is SFINAEd away because the visible `std::begin` cannot take a `std::array`.

Now, if you remove the inclusions of `<iterator>` and `<utility>` altogether (keeping `<array>` after `std_begin_callable`), then compilation fails because the compiler will no longer see any overload of `std::begin` or `std::declval`:

```
template <class T> constexpr auto
std_begin_callable (T const*) -> decltype (std::begin (std::declval <T>()), bool ()) 
{ return true; } // error: begin/declval is not a member of std

template <class> constexpr bool
std_begin_callable (...) 
{ return false; }

#include <array>

static_assert (std_begin_callable <std::array <int, 3>> (0), "failed");

int main () {}
```

Finally, you can replicate/simplify the previous erroneous behavior with this:

```
namespace std {

  void begin();

  template <typename T>
  T&& declval();

}

template <class T> constexpr auto
std_begin_callable (T const*) -> decltype (std::begin (std::declval <T>()), bool ()) 
{ return true; } // No compiler error here, just SFINAE.

template <class> constexpr bool
std_begin_callable (...) 
{ return false; }

#include <array>

static_assert (std_begin_callable <std::array <int, 3>> (0), "failed");

int main () {}
```

**Update:**

From the comments (here and in the OP) I guess it's not possible to solve the header file order issue in the way you wanted. Let me suggest then, a workaround based on ADL that's close to a solution and, possibly (but may be not), good enough for your use case:

```
// <your_header_file>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

namespace detail {

    using std::begin;

    template <typename T, typename = decltype(begin(*((T*)0)))>
    constexpr std::true_type std_begin_callable(int) { return std::true_type(); }

    template <typename>
    constexpr std::false_type std_begin_callable(long) { return std::false_type(); };

};

template <typename T>
constexpr auto std_begin_callable() ->
  decltype(detail::std_begin_callable<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(0)) {
  return detail::std_begin_callable<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(0);
}
// </your_header_file>   

// <a_supposedly_std_header_file>
namespace std {
    struct foo { int begin() /* const */; }; 
    struct bar;
    int begin(/*const*/ bar&);

    template <typename T> struct goo;

    template <typename T>
    int begin(/*const*/ goo<T>&);
}
// </a_supposedly_std_header_file>

// <a_3rd_party_header_file>
namespace ns {

    struct foo { int begin() /*const*/; };
    struct bar;
    int begin(/*const*/ bar&);

    template <typename T> struct goo;

    template <typename T>
    int begin(/*const*/ goo<T>&);

}
// </a_3rd_party_header_file>

//<some_tests>
static_assert ( std_begin_callable</*const*/ std::foo>(), "failed");
static_assert ( std_begin_callable</*const*/ std::bar>(), "failed");
static_assert ( std_begin_callable</*const*/ std::goo<int>>(), "failed");

static_assert ( std_begin_callable</*const*/ ns::foo>(), "failed");
static_assert ( std_begin_callable</*const*/ ns::bar>(), "failed");
static_assert ( std_begin_callable</*const*/ ns::goo<int>>(), "failed");
//</some_tests>

int main () {}
```

It seems to work but I haven't fully tested. I suggest you to try several combinations with/without the commented out `const`s in the code.

I used `*((T*)0)` instead of `std::declval<T>()` because a constness issue. To see it, put `declval` back, and try the `static_assert` for `const ns::foo` leaving `ns::foo::begin` non-`const`.

Comment: And if I'm not completely mistaken (again), regarding the comments of @Andy Prowl, the "first use" of the `begin` template is during the declaration of the SFINAE functions and hence, any specialization should occur before. In other words, replacing `array` by `valarray` (or by a custom class specializing `begin`) would break your first example, wouldn't it? (I'm still concerned about the order of inclusion of headers, last point in my original post.)

Comment: Apparently that's the case, I'm afraid :-( For instance, `static_assert (std_begin_callable <foo> (0), "failed");` will fire or not depending on whether `class foo{}; namespace std { int begin(const foo&); }` preceeds or follows the definition of `std_begin_callable`.